# Cannot download Xcode 7 Beta 2 app to iPhone running iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, ios8.4

I am using Xcode 7 Beta 2 on my Mac. I recently downloaded IOS 8.4 on my iPhone 6. IOS 8.4 was the public release **NOT** 8.4 Beta. When I plug in my iPhone into my Mac to download it to my phone, but next to my iPhone section it says *iPhone (unavailable)*. The deployment target is IOS 8.4. I suspect that this has something to do with the Xcode 7 Beta 2 not being supported with my newly update IOS 8.4 iPhone 6. And I had update a previous version of my app onto my phone when it was running on IOS 8.3. Could someone confirm my belief or help me solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find ios8.4 sdk from Xcode 6.4,Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport,and copy to your Xcode 7.Path:Path: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Comment: I really don't think modifying the contents of the Xcode bundle is supported behavior...

Comment: @grahamcracker1234 :-)

Comment: @matt emm...I was hesitated for install ios9 on my iphone6 plus, my iPad 3 was working slow on ios8, so I tried to install ios9 for it

Comment: @matt trust me you can copy all of the files and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Check the deployment target in xcode project settings deployment info....

Comment: I have the deployment target set to 8.4

Answer (score -1):

Your belief is right. You can't run from Xcode 7 on a device with iOS 8. (You might manage to do it by jiggery-pokery, but the results are unreliable.) You need to install iOS 9 on the device.

Comment: Well I was able to do it with iOS 8.3 on my iPhone 6 before I updated it.

Comment: But if that is the only way, I might as well. But one smaller question. Usually beta versions are buggy. Do u happen to know it iOS 9 beta is glitchy

Comment: Well, let's just say I wouldn't install it on my only device if I were you. :)

Comment: "Well I was able to do it with iOS 8.3 on my iPhone 6 before I updated it" Yes, I've heard that. But I've also heard that the results are very odd, as I said in my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to uninstall iOS 9. And my app is a iPhone app only. So if I downloaded it to my iPad would it know that it is an iPhone only app or would it just download as an iPad app.

Comment: There is no way to go backwards from iOS 9 as far as I know; Apple's site warns clearly about this. An iPhone app will run on your iPad in "emulation mode".